# if value between table.column and table.column then

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm super new at SQL and I'm trying to do an exercise where I have this IRPF_TABLE:

```
IRPF LOWER_VALUE UPPER_VALUE PERCENTAJE
```

---

```
     1          0      12449   ,19       
     2      12450      20199   ,24       
     3      20200      35199    ,3        
     4      35200      59999   ,37       
     5      60000      99999   ,45
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
DECLARE
    salary_month NUMBER(10,2) := 1000;
    salary_anual NUMBER (10,2);
    irpf_perc NUMBER (10, 2);
    irpf_to_pay NUMBER (10, 2);
    
BEGIN
    salary_anual := salary_month * 12;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(salary_month);
    IF salary_anual BETWEEN irpf_table.lower_value AND irpf_table.upper_value THEN
        SELECT percentaje INTO irpf_perc FROM IRPF_TABLE;
    END IF;
    irpf_to_pay := salary_anual * irpf_perc / 100;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(salary_anual);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(irpf_perc);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(irpf_to_pay);
END;
```

OUTPUT:

Informe de error -
ORA-06550: línea 10, columna 39:
PLS-00357: La referencia a la tabla, vista o secuencia 'IRPF_TABLE.LOWER_VALUE' no está permitida en este contexto
ORA-06550: línea 10, columna 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

It says that the reference to the table, 'IRPF_TABLE.LOWER_VALUE' isn't allowed in this context. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. As I said I'm totally new with SQL. I know there is something wrong in my IF condition but I'm lost about it.
Thnak you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of if else like below

```
IF salary_anual BETWEEN irpf_table.lower_value AND irpf_table.upper_value THEN
        SELECT percentaje INTO irpf_perc FROM IRPF_TABLE;
    END IF;
```

You need to use the condition in where clause like this:

```
  SELECT percentaje INTO irpf_perc FROM IRPF_TABLE
    where  salary_anual  BETWEEN lower_value AND upper_value;
```

Working query:

```
  DECLARE
        salary_month NUMBER(10,2) := 1000;
        salary_anual NUMBER (10,2);
        irpf_perc NUMBER (10, 2);
        irpf_to_pay NUMBER (10, 2);
BEGIN
    salary_anual := salary_month * 12;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(salary_month);
    SELECT percentaje INTO irpf_perc FROM IRPF_TABLE
    where  salary_anual  BETWEEN lower_value AND upper_value;
    
    irpf_to_pay := salary_anual * irpf_perc / 100;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(salary_anual);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(irpf_perc);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(irpf_to_pay);
END;
```

Output:

```
Statement processed.
1000
12000
19
2280
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. As I'm practising anonymous blocks I was thinking only about loops or ifs to resolve it.

Comment: You are most welcome. Please accept it if this answer helped you. Best wishes.

Comment: @Weenhallo: Just a hint. Whether you are working with anonymous blocks, procedures, functions, packages, or even another rdbms **always** look for a SQL solution. Yes there are times when standard program (loops, if, get, ... ) constructs may be required. When working with a rdbms straight SQL is virtually always the best choice and should be your first objective. At first that will be difficult as you need to develop a different way of think about problems. But in time it becomes natural, and your db operations dramatically so.

Comment: Excellent suggestion @Belayer. In RDBS always SQL first thinking helps a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing the table in IF, but - it is *unknown* in this context so you got an error. Perhaps you meant

```
SELECT percentaje 
  INTO irpf_perc 
  FROM IRPF_TABLE
  WHERE salary_anual BETWEEN lower_value AND upper_value;
```

but - using that, you'll most probably get an error (`too_many_rows`) if more than single person has annual salary which is between lower and upper value. Or, `no_data_found` if nobody has it.

Depending on what you want to do with that piece of code, you can handle it, either by using exception handling section, or do it in a loop, or fetch data into a collection, or whatever else.

As you posted piece of code that doesn't work, but missed to post sample data, desired output (based on data) and last (but not least) **explain** what you want to do (using plain English), we can't help much, apart from trying to guess.

Comment: So much thank you! I was stuck thinking on an if as the only option.I'm just practising exercises about anonymous blocks. So for know I don't have those problems...